# How do I count certain records in one table based while excluding records based on date values in another table?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

**I am tasked with Producing count of Users asked to Acknowledge various Documents.
However the data is an event log and the data model does not match the business rules.**

I am not very familiar with PowerBI or DAX and this problem is taxing my brain.

The system I am trying to report on is a document management system. A `Document` goes through two workflows.

1. The `Authoring Workflow` where an Editor firsts `Edits` and then `Publishes` a Document.
2. The `Acknowledgement Workflow` where `Users` are asked to `Acknowledge` the Published Document. This step can be repeated several times concurrently or sequentially.

- Optionally repeat #1 and #2 several times per Document.

The business rules dictate once a document is published the previous Acknowledgement Requests are to be ignored, however the Acknowledgement Requests in the Tables.

For example if a document has been through the Authoring and Acknowledgement cycle twice, the fist time 5 users were asked to acknowledge. The second time 2 users were asked to acknowledge. There is another document where 1 user were asked to Acknowledge, the total number of Users Requested is 3. (2+1) Not 8. (5+2+1)

All data is present in the report, the relationships are defined. The business logic may not be changed, and the data model may have columns and tables added to it. So long as they are derived from the existing data.

Thank you so much in advance!

```
// Tables
Document: Id, Description
Activity: Workflow Id*, Type, User, Executed, Acknowledged
Workflow: Document Id*, Workflow Id, Type,
```

#### Sample Data

Document

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| D1 | Document One |
| D2 | Document Two |

Workflow

| Document Id | Type | Workflow Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | Authoring | W1 |
| D1 | Acknowledgement | W2 |
| D1 | Acknowledgement | W3 |
| D1 | Authoring | W4 |
| D1 | Acknowledgement | W5 |
| D2 | Authoring | W6 |
| D2 | Acknowledgement | W7 |

Activity

| Workflow Id | Type | User | Executed | Acknowledgement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W1 | Edited | U1 | 1/1/2000 | na (null) |
| W1 | Published | U1 | 1/3/2000 | na |
| W2 | Request Acknowledgement | U2 | 1/4/2000 | null |
| W2 | Request Acknowledgement | U3 | 1/4/2000 | 1/5/2000 |
| W3 | Request Acknowledgement | U4 | 1/5/2000 | null |
| W3 | Request Acknowledgement | U5 | 1/5/2000 | 1/5/2000 |
| W3 | Request Acknowledgement | U6 | 1/5/2000 | 1/5/2000 |
| W4 | Edited | U1 | 1/6/2000 | na (null) |
| W4 | Published | U1 | 1/7/2000 | na (null) |
| W5 | Request Acknowledgement | U2 | 1/8/2000 | null |
| W5 | Request Acknowledgement | U6 | 1/8/2000 | 1/9/2000 |
| W6 | Edited | U1 | 1/1/2000 | na (null) |
| W6 | Published | U1 | 1/3/2000 | na (null) |
| W7 | Request Acknowledgement | U2 | 1/5/2000 | 1/8/2000 |

Workflow `W4` should cause the previous 5 requests from `W2`, and `W3` to be ignored.

Expected Results: A bar chart containing two bars.

```
Total Requests     | === 3
Completed Requests | == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to identify the most recent 'Publish' activity for each document and most recent 'Acknowledgment' Request.

For Publish You can do this by adding a calculated column to the Workflow table. something like this should work

```
CALCULATE(
    MAX(Activity[Executed]),
    FILTER(
        Activity,
        Activity[Workflow Id] = EARLIER(Workflow[Workflow Id])
        && Activity[Type] = "Published"
    )
)
```

For 'Acknowledgment' create another calculated column

```
VAR CurrentWorkflowId = Activity[Workflow Id]
VAR DocumentId = LOOKUPVALUE(Workflow[Document Id], Workflow[Workflow Id], CurrentWorkflowId)
VAR MostRecentPublishDate = CALCULATE(
                                MAX(Workflow[MostRecentPublishDate]),
                                FILTER(
                                    Workflow,
                                    Workflow[Document Id] = DocumentId
                                )
                            )
RETURN IF(Activity[Type] = "Request Acknowledgement" && Activity[Executed] > MostRecentPublishDate, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Then you just need to create two measures to count them
Total requests

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Activity),
    Activity[IsRelevantAcknowledgment] = TRUE
)
```

and Total Acknowledgements

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Activity),
    Activity[IsRelevantAcknowledgment] = TRUE,
    NOT ISBLANK(Activity[Acknowledged])
)
```

let me know if this works